# Correct use of 'to entail'

Tags: word-usage, implication

Let's say I found a very nice description of all the aspects you have to describe when you want to write cooking instructions for a meal. Now I want to share that what I found is a nice description of all the parts you have to think of when writing cooking instructions.  Also I want to use the word `entail`.

Now, what I wrote down is the following.

> This is a really nice description of what cooking instructions entail.

Is this a correct way of using `entail`?

Comment: Why are you unsure about it? You've looked up definitions and examples of 'entail', I assume. What's the difficulty?

Comment: Thanks for asking. Because it sounds a little bit off and to my surprise the [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entail) is to restrict or impose, which made me think whether `entail` has a negative connotation, while the sentence is a positive one.

Comment: What is entailed by something may be good or bad, but the word 'entail' itself has no automatic negative (or positive) implication. Making an omelette or cake entails breaking eggs, but there is nothing negative about an omelette or a cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a correct use of *to entail*.

In that sort of usage, *A* ***entailing*** *B* means that it is a necessary component. As Merriam-Webster online puts it:

> "to impose, involve, or imply as a necessary accompaniment or result"

It could be imposed (by some authority), imply (such as by convention), or involve (by definition) that B is a necessary element or accompaniment, or a result (usually meaning that it is to some degree inevitable).

So, your sentence says that '*this*', whatever it refers to, is a really nice description of what '*cooking instructions*', instructions regarding cooking, '*entail*' - which is to say, what they are expected to contain or result in. From context, it's obvious that this refers to expectations about content (and requirements, contents and accompaniments are a more common use of *to entail* than results in any case).

This does not necessarily imply any use of authority or imposition, rather it can be a statement about generally understood expectations.